# Затруднение с созданием файла через fstream

Tags: c++

У меня возникла проблема: не создается файл, который должен заполняться определенными значениями.

Раньше не объявлял в головном файле массивы через С++шную конструкцию new, ..в этом беда (комбинирование fstream и new int вместо realloc/malloc?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

geometry.cpp:

```
void input_geometryY(int *M,int n) 
{         
    int i;
    FILE * input_fiY; 
    input_fiY = fopen("input_geometryY.txt", "w"); 

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        M[i]=rand()%100;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    { 
        M[i] = rand() % 100;
        fprintf(input_fiY,"M[%i] = %d ",i, M[i]);
    }

    fclose(input_fiY); 
}
```

main.cpp:

```
printf("-------Вводятся данные с файла, расположенного в папке с приложением...-------");
printf("\n");
int* A=new int[n]; // Икс-координаты точек
input_geometryX(A, n);

int* B=new int[n]; // Икс-координаты точек
input_geometryY(B, n);

Print(A,n); 
Print(B,n); 

delete[] A;
delete[] B;
```

Comment: Простите, но у вас ошибка в `fscanf`, работа с не открытым файлом (указатель NULL) -  что очень ясно видно на фото, вы же приводите обрывок с `fprintf`. Что-то у вас не то, правда? Да и выводимое сообщение на экран не соответствует приведенному в коде, так? Так что давайте **актуальный** код. И еще - вы не первый, кто пишет "ввод с файла" - это что, теперь в русском так принято? Не "из", а "с"? И не надо оправдываться, что это не урок русского - еще Дейкстра говорил, что человек, не знающий родной язык, язык программирования освоить не сумеет :)

Comment: Вдогонку - вы пишете "комбинирование fstream" - где? Вы не используете `fstream`, а работаете с `FILE*` из C...

Comment: Я не использую fscanf, ведь в этом нет нужды, так как массив генерируется в цикле, а затем просто выводится. Зачем мне после вывода ещё раз сканировать в итерационном исчислении?

Comment: @Harry, мне прям жалко этих студентов, на дворе 2020 скоро выйдет c++20 уже, а их до сих пор учат на vs2010 если вообще не 2008 судя по скриншоту, заставляют работать с сырыми указателями и писать на непонятной смеси из c99 и c++98, понятно почему после таких учителей большинство считает что язык c++ сложный/устаревший..

Comment: @Arenoros,  Выражаясь так , думаю, вы можете отбить у любого охоту учиться. Во вторых, не  вежливо звучит :"мне жалко их".  Не согласен, что  изучая С++, можно или лучше игнорировать все, что было до С++11 и знание работы с сырыми указателями.

Comment: OK, тогда приведите минимальный компилируемый пример. Такой, чтобы его можно было скомпилировать, выполнить *указанные вами* действия и получить сбой. Как только это будет сделано - можно будет о чем-то говорить, а пока - минус и голос за закрытие вопроса. Тем более что еще и его заголовок противоречит содержанию!

Comment: @Arenoros Ну, как говорил мой дед, "что знаешь и умеешь - за плечами не носить", уметь нужно побольше, в том числе и работать с голыми указателями. Это не так страшно :) Искажать информацию (эдакий эвфемизм сами понимаете чего) - куда хуже...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, Вы не правильно меня поняли, я как раз таки наоборот хочу чтоб появлялись новые адепты С++) А таким подходом к обучению это затрудняет их появление. И жаль мне их искренне, я сам был студентом, и по своему опыту помню как на параллельных потоках преподы показывали этот язык исключительно с худшей стороны. Можно и лучше игнорировать сырые указатели на **начальном** этапе обучения, это уже было доказано более компетентными людми в вопросах обучения c++)

Comment: Если бы ещё так все хорошо было. Как справедливо говорит Гарри, не только vs2008 а ещё и совмещение Си и С++, пример будет вечером. Впрочем, если прописать прототип - будет "работать" и сейчас.

Comment: Могу только посоветовать доклад как должно выглядеть обучение c++, найти автора и остальное думаю не составит труда) И раз уже вы на win32 поставьте уже 2019 студию, у неё есть бесплатная версия и там гораздо более приятный процесс разработки. Вот сам доклад https://youtu.be/mhiAXYprh34

Comment: void input_geometryY(int *M,int n) 
{ 
int i;
FILE * input_fiY; 
input_fiY = fopen("input_geometryY.txt", "w"); 


for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{ 
    fprintf(input_fiY,"M[%i] = %d ",i, M[i]);
  }

fclose(input_fiY); 

} 
Так правильно

Answer (score 0):

добавьте проверку открытия файла

```
FILE * input_fiY; 
if (input_fiY = fopen("input_geometryY.txt", "w")==NULL) {
printf("Cannot open file.\n");
exit(1);
}
```